# coord_map() of ggplot2 ignores plot.background and produces white margins – how to remove them?

Tags: r, ggplot2

## Problem

Greetings, I'm trying to plot a map with a dark background using `ggplot2` by setting the `theme()` parameter `plot.background` to e.g. `element_rect(fill = "#000000")` but switching from the cartesian coordinate system to a map projection using `coord_map()` introduces white margins which can only be removed by adjusting the size of the plot to the same ratio as the map area.

How can I remove this margin and apply the fill colour specified using the `plot.background` parameter to the whole plot regardless of its ratio?

## MWE

```
nz <- map_data("nz")
ggplot(nz, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
    geom_polygon(fill = "white", colour = "black") +
    coord_map() +
    theme_void() +
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#000000"))
```

## Output

[image: Output with a white margin]

## Expected output

[image: Expected output without a white margin]

## Update

After about two hours of trying different approaches and wondering how R plotting and especially ggplot2 can be so incredibly clumsy, I finally found a solution [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/269269) but it requires another library and additional steps to produce this conceptually elementary adjustment which should really be the default in the first place so there surely must be a native solution… right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution with the grid package, which is the package ggplot2 uses to draw the plots. First, I would make the small adjustment to your plotting code by also setting the plot background colour to black:

```
g <- ggplot(nz, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(fill = "white", colour = "black") +
  coord_map() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#000000", colour = "#000000"))
```

Next we convert the `g` to a `gtable` and draw it with the grid package:

```
library(grid)
gt <- ggplotGrob(g)
grid.newpage()
# Draw a black rectangle
grid.draw(rectGrob(gp = gpar(fill = "#000000")))
grid.draw(gt)
```

The problem is that many coord-functions set a fixed aspect ratio for the plot, which will in turn affect other plot elements that are defined in absolute dimensions.

Comment: Thank you, this works very well! It also looks like the `cowplot` library which I found uses this same approach so it indeed appears to be the best available solution. If no one provides a ‘native’ one in the next day or two, I'll accept your answer. I'm just surprised `ggplot2` doesn't do this by default because while I understand the need for a fixed aspect ratio in those cases, `plot.background` should always affect the whole background, which is clearly possible and not that difficult if you have experience and know what's going on. Anyway, thanks again, this was a major pain! :)